# How can I manipulate $\frac { \sqrt { x+1 } }{ \sqrt { x } +1 } $ to find $M>0$ to prove a limit?

Tags: calculus

Given the following limit, find such an $M>0$ that for every $x>M$, the expression is $\frac { 1 }{ 3 }$ close to the limit. In other words find $M>0$ that for every $x>M:\left| f(x)-L \right| <\frac { 1 }{ 3 }$ for the following function:

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { \sqrt { x+1 }  }{ \sqrt { x } +1 } =1 } $$

Steps I took:

$$\left| \frac { \sqrt { x+1 }  }{ \sqrt { x } +1 } -1 \right| <\frac { 1 }{ 3 } $$

$$\Longrightarrow \left| \frac { \sqrt { x+1 }  }{ \sqrt { x } +1 } -\frac { \sqrt { x } +1 }{ \sqrt { x } +1 }  \right| <\frac { 1 }{ 3 } $$

$$\Longrightarrow \left| \frac { \sqrt { x+1 } -\sqrt { x } -1 }{ \sqrt { x } +1 }  \right| <\frac { 1 }{ 3 } $$

How can I manipulate the function inside of the absolute value in order to simplify this and find a lower bound $x$ (the M)?

Answer (score 1):

The usual rationalization:

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}
&=(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}\\
&< \frac1{2\sqrt{x}}
\end{array}
$

Comment: I can't seem to see the big picture. Meaning, how to apply what you've demonstrated to the actual problem.

Comment: Combine this with what you have and you get $\left| \frac { \sqrt { x+1 } -\sqrt { x } -1 }{ \sqrt { x } +1 }  \right|  < |\frac{1+1/(2\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}|$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for an intuitive solution:

$$\left|\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x}+1}-1\right|<\left|\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x}}-1\right|=\left|\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x}}-1\right|=\left|\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}-1\right|.$$
Now by letting that $x\to\infty$ then the result follows.

Comment: So, $\left|\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}-1\right|$ as $x$ approaches infinity means that $x>0$ so, we can say that $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}-1<\frac { 1 }{ 3 } $ ?

Comment: sure, the expression tends to zero, for $x>0$ large enough

Comment: if you want to know when $<\frac{1}{3}$, try to solve $x$ from $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{1}{3}$ first

Answer (score 1):

First rationalization

i.e. $\left|\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}+1}\right|$
= $\left|\frac{(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}-1)}{x-1}\right|$

=$\left|\frac{\sqrt{x(x+1)}-\sqrt{x+1}-x+1}{x-1}\right|$

Then, we could choose M to be a particular value to solve the problem(by taking maximum of M at last). In this case, take $M=2$

$\because x > M = 2$

$\frac{x}{2} > 1$

$\therefore$ $<\left|\frac{\sqrt{x+1}(\sqrt{x}-1)-x+1}{x-\frac{x}{2}}\right|$

=$\left|(\frac{2}{x})(\sqrt{x+1}(\sqrt{x}-1)-x+1)\right|$

<$\left|(\frac{2}{x})(\sqrt{x+x}(\sqrt{x}-1)-x+1)\right|,x>2$

=$\left|(\frac{2}{x})(2x-2\sqrt{x}-x+1)\right|$

=$\left|(\frac{2}{x})(1-\sqrt{x})^2\right|$

<$\left|(1-\sqrt{x})^2\right|$<$\frac{1}{3},x>2$

$\because (1-\sqrt{x})^2 < \frac{1}{3}$

$ x > (1-\sqrt\frac{1}{3})^2$

Therefore, take $M = max${${(1-\sqrt\frac{1}{3})^2},2$}$=2$